# Symfony login functionality strange behaviour

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have implemented security area with symfony2 login functionality. I have noticed that on every request (ajax and normal one) it executes my loadUserByUsername function, in which i have the logic for retrieving user from the database and checking if it is a valid one. 
Is this normal behaviour for symfony2 login functionality or have i done something wrong?

Comment: Well, how would you login elsehow? ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by serializing the User object (by default only the "id" attribute is serialized, which is why everytime the refreshUser method reloads the User by calling loadUserByUsername).

Please refer to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html for more information, especially the section on "What is the importance of serialize and unserialize?"